# generating R images dynamically

Tags: r

There are bunch of files that are updated on a directory called: c:/files. These files are R data files that have R ojects in them. When I load these files, I get different objects that have data in them. For example, if I load the opening.R file, I get ojects like opening.stock, opening.options, opening.bonds etc. I like to load each of these .R files and go though them and create images based on objects and them them as file name plus object name .png. Below is my code but it is not quite working. I can load the file and read the ojects. But when I try to read the content of the objects, it is not working. Any ideas, what I am doing wrong:

```
for (file in dir("c:\\files" ,pattern = "OPENING")){
load(file)

    for (object in ls()) {
        ## if I like to see the content of the oject
        ## I do this
        ### print(oject) 
        ### this does not work, it just prints oject, not the content of objects   
        png("file+ojbect.png")
        plot(object)
        dev.off()
    }
}
```

I used get(oject) as suggested by @Ben Bolker but I have another issue now. I have a date column that that I have to convert to as.Date and sort it so that it plots well as below:

```
     x=as.data.frame(get(oject))
    x$Date<- as.Date(x$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
    x<- x[order(as.Date(x$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")),]
```

I get this error:

```
Error in as.Date.default(x$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d") :
  do not know how to convert 'x$Date' to class "Date"
Calls: as.Date -> as.Date.default
Execution halted
```

I am still having problems. First iteration work but when it comes to the second file, it chokes:

```
suppressMessages(library(ggplot2))
suppressMessages(library(gridExtra))
suppressMessages(library(timeDate))

    for (i in dir("c:\\tmp" ,pattern = "OPENNING")){
        setwd("C:/tmp") 
        load(i)
        print(i)
        Sys.sleep(5)
            for (object in ls()) {
                x<-data.frame(get(object))
                print(x)
                x$Date<-as.Date(timeDate(x$Date))      
                x[order(x$Date),] 
                png((openning.png",sep="")
                Plot(x)
                dev.off()
            }
    }
```

error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "TimeStamp", value = numeric(0)) :
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 7
Calls: $<- -> $<-.data.frame
Execution halted
```

Please dont down vote my post if you dont have any input. How else am I supposed to ask this question.

Comment: `ls()` gives you a list of the *names* of objects, not a list of objects [see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haddocks%27_Eyes ].  Try `get(object)` everywhere you have `object` (although someone may suggest a better way to do this)

Comment: FYI: "Evolving" questions like this are generally considered bad practice on SO. When you keep coming back with follow-ups like this, it's a sure sign that you did a poor job of writing a good, reproducible question in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the date problem:

```
 x=as.data.frame(get(object))
    x$Date<- as.Date(x$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
    x<- x[order(x$Date)),]   
 # if the conversion was successful a Date class object can be ordered
```

Comment: I cannot believe it, I already try this did not work and now it is working. I have one more question and I think I should be ok. for the png files, I like to name them file+object.png. if I do png("file+object.png", it does not work, any ideas on this?

Comment: do you mean `png(paste0("file+",object,".png"))` (`paste0` is only in the most recent version of R, otherwise use `paste(...,sep="")` ?

Comment: did not work: I am still getting this error: Error in as.Date.default(x$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d") : do not know how to convert 'x$Date' to class "Date" Calls: as.Date -> as.Date.default Execution halted. When I do the exact same thing on the R window, it works

Comment: @DWin, I initially thought it was working but not working. I am not able to convert x$Date to as.Date format. I can do this in R command line window but when I try to do the samething with a script, not working.

Comment: I used library(timeDate)) get around this problem. Thanks everyone. Again, awesome help, I appreciate it.

Comment: The `as.data.frame` was probably superfluous, since they should already have been dataframes and if you ar eworing within functions it is always safe to use the form `x[["colname"]]` than to use the '$' function.

Comment: after the first loop, I had to put this in there to clean up the objects:  rm(list=ls()) and it work. Hopefully this comment will help others trying to do the same.